# ForgeRock AM 6.5, OpenDJ unable to force users to change password after reset

Tags: authentication, ldap, openam, opendj, forgerock

ForgeRock AM 6.5, OpenDJ

I am trying to ask users to change their password once it has been reset by the admin on ForgeRock AM 6.5 with OpenDJ. I have enabled the `force-change-on-reset` flag under the password policy along with the `pwdReset` user attribute.

Surprisingly, after admin resets the password, the user attribute `pwdReset` becomes `TRUE`, but without any prompt or alert to change the password after login. The user continues to use the service the way it is.

The `pwdReset` field is only disabled when the user manually goes to the settings and changes the password.

How do I force the password reset screen, am I missing something here? Do I need to create a custom node in order to read the user attributes after login and redirect in case `pwdReset` is true?

Note: I am not using any custom UI as of now, and only doing my development using the standard out of the box ForgeRock XUI.

Thanks!

Comment: the PasswordPolicy response controls are only taken into account when you use the LDAP auth module. The 'datastore' auth module will not handle them.

Comment: Yep, I am using LDAP as the authentication module in my tree, but still, it's not happening.